# .where() firestore query not working properly?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

In the below code, when I remove the .where() from my query the query works and I get my comments returned. However, when I use the where query to try and find a comment bound to a post (scream) id, i get a blank array. Am I using .where() incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

```
  exports.getScream = (req, res) => {

let screamData = {};
db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {

    screamData = doc.data();
    screamData.screamId = doc.id;
    return db
      .collection('comments')
      .where('screamId', '==', screamData.screamId) //query that doesnt seem to be working
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .get();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    screamData.comments = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      screamData.comments.push(doc.data());
    });
    return res.json(screamData);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
  });
  }
```

Firestore document model

```
{
screamId: “id of post commenting on”,
body: “content of comment”,
userHandle: “username of comment”
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't OrderBy be before the where?

Comment: Even when I remove orderBy, it still doesn’t work@AndréKool

Comment: I never said to remove it. Have you tried placing the orderBy before the where part of the query instead of the where before orderBy like you have in your code now?

Comment: Yes still no luck

Comment: In that case you need to include more information in your question like a picture of your database structure and the exact value you are using in the where query

Comment: Sure, will update shortly

Comment: @AndréKool added DB structure of “comments” collection

Comment: tried everything and no luck, any help is appreciated

Comment: The orderBy has a field that doesn't appear in your structure. That won't work.