# React Native Firestore Get Comments From Posts

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So im having collection comments, collection users and collection posts. How to query firestore so that I get posts and ITS comments on my feed screen? I can pay for help if needed. My collection comments has a field for helping with this called "postId" and my collection posts has field "userHandle" also to help with this. but how to do this query?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken a look at this: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#one-time-read? For querying look at this: https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querying.

Comment: have you tried to put comments as sub-collection to posts.

Comment: i kinda tried everything. im doing this ONE query for 2 weeks now every day:P. I just need ONE query. I need a query that is giving me: ALL posts with ALL comments that belong to their exact post. thats all i need... i wrote the comments inside firebase I just need a query where a comment would know to which post it belongs.

Comment: I NEED THIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994387/where-firestore-query-not-working-properly EXACTLY THIS. BUT this is written for React, i need this a bit more for react native.

Comment: The link I posted earlier (rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querying) shows how you could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query your comments collection you can do something like this.

```
const postId = "y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT" // example id of a post document
firestore()
  .collection('comments')
  // Filter results
  .where('postId', '==', postId)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    if (querySnapshot.exists) {
      // Do something with the data
    }
  });
```

This retrieves all comment documents where the `postId` field equals the value you pass in.

Comment: i like this response, but i tried it and i have no idea how that gives me empty array... im literally looking in my firebase and i have comments under certain post. for example: i wrote exactly your code but tried to write this line like this: .where('postId', '==', "exactStringIDofThePost")  and i get empty array even tho there are comments in a field collection with field postId that matches exactStringIDofThePost. so yeah if someone wants to help me i can pay

Comment: Why doesnt this work:     `const postId = db.collection("posts").doc("y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT");
  let lista = [];
  const yo = Fire.shared.firestore
    .collection("comments")
    // Filter results
    .where("postId", "==", postId)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const PostItem = doc.data();
        //PostItem.id = doc.id;
        lista.push(PostItem);
      });
    });
  console.log(lista); //returns EMPTY ARRAY?`

Comment: The way you set postId is wrong. `y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT` is the post document id, so set the variable  to that (as a string). `y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT` should be a field value of postId in one or more comment documents.

Comment: but it is. u say "y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT should be a field value of postId in one or more comment documents.". in my comments collection, each document has a field value of postId, and one of those documents has exactly y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT as postId value? so i dont get what ur saying. With my comments each of them has postId and they are equal to some of posts document id. so thats how im trying for this to work. i just need that query.

Comment: Have you changed the passed in postId as I suggested? I've edited my post and added an example.

Comment: `const postId = "y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT"; // example id of a post document
  var lista = [];
  
  db.collection("comments")
    // Filter results
    .where("postId", "==", postId)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const PostItem = doc.data();
        //PostItem.id = doc.id;
        lista.push(PostItem);
      });
    });
  console.log(lista); //SHOWS EMPTY ARRAY  btw im absolutely sure that yes one of documents (aka comment) in collection comments under field postId has value y7FN13SKWUDsWdKsGJiT still this isnt working?`

Comment: Retrieving things from Firestore is asynchronous. Pushing the items to `listsa` might not have happened yet when you're logging the list. Try logging out `doc.data()` inside the forEach loop first.